# Gitlab-ci lost environment variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, semantic-versioning

I'm developing a pipeline on GitLab-ci, in the first job I use `gittools/gitversion` the obtain the semantic version of my software.

Here a small piece of code of `/gitversion-ci-cd-plugin-extension.gitlab-ci.yml` (Full documentation here https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/build-servers/gitlab)

```yaml
.gitversion_function:
  image:
    name: gittools/gitversion
    entrypoint: ['']
  stage: .pre
  .....
  .....
  artifacts:
    reports:
      #propagates variables into the pipeline level
      dotenv: thisversion.env
```

Then a simplified version of my pipeline is as follows

```yaml
stages:
  - .pre
  - install_dependencies
  - build
  - deploy


include:
  - local: '/gitversion-ci-cd-plugin-extension.gitlab-ci.yml'


determineversion:
  extends: .gitversion_function

  
install_dependencies:
  image: node:16.14
  stage: install_dependencies
  script:
    - echo ${PACKAGE_VERSION}


build:
  image: node:16.14
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo $PACKAGE_VERSION


deploy:
  image: bitnami/kubectl
  stage: deploy
  needs: ['build']
  script:
    - echo $PACKAGE_VERSION
```

The problem is that the environment variable `$PACKAGE_VERSION` works in the first two jobs `install_dependencies` and `build`.

```
echo $PACKAGE_NAME;  //0.0.1
```

But when the jobs `deploy` is executed the environment variable is not expanded by pipeline and I obtain literally this

```
echo $PACKAGE_NAME;  //$PACKAGE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
In the last job of my pipeline, I use `needs` (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) to establish dependencies between jobs.
The problem is that artifact is not automatically passed because there is no a dependency between `determineversion` and `deploy`, to fix I do this:

```
...
deploy:
  image: bitnami/kubectl
  stage: deploy
  needs: ['determineversion', 'build']  # <------
  script:
    - echo $PACKAGE_VERSION
...
```

I added `determineversion` as a dependency of `deploy`, in this way `$PACKAGE_VERSION` is printed correctly